# Sugarcrm set_relationship between custom module and contacts in Java

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

I'm trying to create a relationtship between a custom module and a contact but after the creation (response is {"deleted":0,"created":1,"failed":0}) I didn't find notwing in the application panel and database relationship table also (only one record manually created). Where is my fault?

the example code:

```
String sessioneID = "xxxxx";
String contactId = "yyyyyy";

Map<String, String> nameValueList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

List<String> relatedIds = new ArrayList<String>();
relatedIds.add(customId);

Map<String, Object> request = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
request.put("session", sessioneID);
request.put("module_name", "Contacts");
request.put("module_id", contactId);
request.put("link_field_name", "custom_contacts");
request.put("related_ids", relatedIds);
request.put("deleted", "0");

List<NameValuePair> formParams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("method", "set_relationships"));
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("input_type", "JSON"));
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_type", "JSON"));
formParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("rest_data", JSONObject.toJSONString(request)));

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://kkkk.com/rest.php");
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(formParams));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpResponse execute = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Thanks